# FileNotFoundException resource file from external directory maven intellij

Tags: maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have some problem running SpringBoot application in Intellij. The @SpringBootApplication is located in the child module

```
└── conf
   └── xml
      └──beans.xml
└── source
   └── core
       └── common
        └── MainApplication.java --> @SpringBootApplication
   └── config
   └── pom.xml --> parent
```

The MainApplication.java have annotation 
@ImportResource("classpath:/beans.xml")

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.xxx.yyy"})
@EnableCaching
@ImportResource("classpath:/beans.xml")
public class ServiceApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer // extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer
{
```

The "config" module has pom.xml, no java file. It only generate the resources

```
<artifactId>config</artifactId>
    <properties>
        <environment>DEV</environment>
        <country>ID</country>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <filters>
            <filter>../../build/server.properties</filter>
        </filters>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>../../conf</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/**/log4j2.xml</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <targetPath>../../../../deploy/conf</targetPath>
            </resource>
...
```

I tried to run configuration on Intellij, but it produce error FileNotFoundException for file beans.xml. This configuration already ran on Eclipse in other teammates. I want to run it on Intellij. I already import config module in Project Structure, and the conf folder already marked as Resource Root. Why its still not work? Or if I have to append change to existing java file or pom, its okay. as long the application can found its way to the resource folder. I dont need to build into war and run it, but I only want to run as SpringBoot application

Thank you. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i would say this is not a standard java project structure .... not good practice.

Go to File -> Project Structure -> Modules  e.g.:

[image]

As you can see there u can edit the Paths to the Source, Resource, Test ... folders  or add more than on.

perhaps this will help...

Answer (score 0):

First: Remove the leading `/` from `@ImportResource("classpath:/beans.xml")`.

This should be:

```
@ImportResource("classpath:beans.xml")
```

Second: Check that you `beans.xml` is copied to your project build directory when resources are processed.

The default location for the `beans.xml` would be `target/classes/beans.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the leading / from @ImportResource("classpath:/beans.xml").

1. It should be like as : `@ImportResource("classpath:beans.xml")`
2. Check whether the source file beans.xml has been copied to the build directory or not:Path : /target/classess/beans.xml
3. If you have not placed the beans.xml in source folder, then provide the actual path or place it inside resource folder